# Share unfinished work (uncommited and new files) via Git

Tags: git

I do my work from three different workstations. I would like to be able to leave a workstation in the middle of a coding sessions and resume this work later on another workstation. Given that the code is shared via a remote git repo, I would like to use git to share this unfinished work.

In practical terms, *unfinished work* means

- there are changed files,
- there are new untracked files,
- there are deleted files.

Most of the times these changes are temporary: not all the changes and most of the untracked files will finish in the final commit. An example of untracked file is a test file duplicated with 20 slightly different modifications for test purposes; I care about all these files only while I'm working on a certain problem and I do not want to lose time regenerating them when switching to another workstation.

I have seen other questions and solutions that use a branch to push these changes: while I am OK with this, there is the problem that these branches will be rewritten every time, requiring a `git push --force` (I do not like `--force` much) or allowing them to become very messy over the time.

**What I would like to have** is a simple command or git alias that allow me to store the current state of the work directory without "messing too much" with the git history. There must be a companion simple command or git alias that allow me to download these temporary changes from the other workstations.

Answer (score 4):

Use git stash to save your changes to a file.

```
git stash
git stash show -p > myPatchFile
```

On the other computer apply them

```
git apply myPatchFile
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You could use `git add -A` to remove deleted and add new files. Then commit it into a branch named say `my_current_work`. Exchange it via remote repo using `--force`. You could share a new one remote which is only for you to make the main repo cleaner. Or if you have a network link between workstations you could push/pull changes directly between them.
   Before merging your work into the master branch you do `rebase -i` to clean up commit history.
2. As alternative to remote repo for exchanging you could send patches via e-mail (`git-send-email`).

Answer (score 0):

You probably could use stash, but I'm not really sure if it would fit.

One option is to create a commit that will add all the needed files, and just cherry pick it, when you need it and remove it using interactive rebase before pushing to public repo.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a personal feature branch (preferably in a personal repo), commit everything, don't rewrite history, use `git commit --fixup=<commit>` to change the unwanted changes introduced by a commit, and when your day work or feature is finished just `git rebase -i` this branch into the main feature branch or master branch.