# Put file immediately in history

Tags: git, git-revert

I have a Git repository with one branch, `master`. Say I have a new, unfinished
file called `foo.txt`.

I have decided that I do not need this file now, but might in the future. So I
would like to be able to find the file in the history, but not on `HEAD`.
I can do this

```sh
git add foo.txt
git commit -m 'Create foo.txt'
git revert master
```

but I am wondering if any other ways are available.

Comment: Why not create a branch to store it? Or use git stash with a useful description?

Comment: @StevenPenny uh, yeah, why don't you just make a branch to keep the file? I wouldn't stash it, it's too easy to just nuke entire stashes with `git stash clear`.

Comment: So this is just my personal opinion. In cases like these, I would just store the file in a branch, push the branch up to a remote repo, then delete the branch locally. Done. Kept forever, or I can delete it on the remote whenever.

Comment: @StevenPenny that doesn't make sense.  there's _nowhere_ you can put a file such that if you delete all references to it, it's still available.  if you want it forever, just _don't delete the branch_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit the file as in the question

```sh
git add foo.txt
git commit -m 'Create foo.txt'
```

Then email myself the patch

```
git send-email -1 --to steven@example.com
```

Then reset

```
git reset @^
```

Optionally you can use `--keep` and it will remove the file from the working
tree

```
git reset --keep @^
```

Credit for the idea

[Share unfinished work (uncommited and new files) via Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10226586/#10227966)

Comment: Patches...of course! But if you're just going to email yourself the patch, why not just save the file itself in your email?

Comment: @Cupcake I saw that other answer and ran with it. My answer is in the spirit of what I was originally trying to do, but your suggestion is simpler, so thanks!